# pac4j configure authorizers with OR

Tags: java, authentication, security, playframework, pac4j

I am using DirectBearerAuthClient with Authorizes.
According to the pac4j default behavior if multiple authorizes aredefined , then all should be stisfied, lets take below example, there are two authorizes and a URL

Authorizer : allowRead, allowRight
URL: /student/action

#Config Ex1:

```
pac4j.security.rules = [
{
    "/student/action" = {
      authorizers = "allowRead,AllowRight"
      clients = "DirectBearerAuthClient"
    }
}

]
```

#Config Ex2:

```
pac4j.security.rules = [
{
    "/student/action" = {
      authorizers = "allowRead"
      clients = "DirectBearerAuthClient"
    }
}

]
```

Ex1 : both Authorizes should be statisifed "allowRead,AllowRight"
to access the URL, so both should be satisfied

Ex2 : only one authorized "allowRead" should be satisfied
to access the URL, if user have "allowWrite" instead of "allowReady" then not to access URL

is it possible to configure Authorize as with 'OR' condition , like
authorizers = "allowRead OR AllowRight", which mean any user has one to these two
authorizes can access the URL  , for example to configure something like

```
pac4j.security.rules = [
{
    "/student/action" = {
      authorizers = "allowRead OR AllowRight"
      clients = "DirectBearerAuthClient"
    }
}

]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authorizers listed in the `authorizers` parameter must be all satisfied, meaning they are treated as "AND".

If you want to implement the "OR" logic, you must define a specific authorizer based on the `OrAuthorizer`. Example:

```java
final Config c = new Config(clients);
c.addAuthorizer("orAuthorizer",
  OrAuthorizer.or(
    new RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer("allowRead"),
    new RequireAnyRoleAuthorizer("AllowRight")
  )
);
return c;
```